# jquery data tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following setup

```
    <div onclick="EditCalendarEvent('@_schedulerEvent.SchedulerID','@_schedulerEvent.SchedulerItemID', event)" 
         class="ScheduleEvent_Draggable ScheduleEvent" 
         data-schedulerID="@_schedulerEvent.SchedulerID"
         data-schedulerItemID="@_schedulerEvent.SchedulerItemID">        
      @_schedulerEvent.Subject
    </div>


    alert($(ui.draggable).attr("data-schedulerID"));
    alert($(ui.draggable).data("schedulerID"));
```

The first alert returns the proper ui, the second alert statment return undefined.

Comment: which version of `jQuery` your are using?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing an example (and I don't use jqueryUI much) but is jqueryUI possibly rewriting the data-*? or moving it to a different node as it might be doing it's own thing? If you can include a sample we can have a look through it.

Comment: What is it that you expected? .data() allows you to access a collection of key:value pairs that have been added to this element. We can attach to, and iterate over events and parameters. In the above, I do not see any 'schedulerId' being bound to the `data` of the `object` in question. If you wanted to add a key:value to the data of the object, then you could add `$('div').click(function(){  $(this).data("schedulerID", 'aNumberHere'); console.log($(this).data('schedulerID')); });`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jQuery you are using. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Please use the latest version of jQuery. This is effective from 1.4 version. Please visit the above link for more information.